# Can’t write to .bashrc: permission denied

Tags: android, bashrc, xbindkeys

I have downloaded NDK for my Eclipse Juno. Now I have to add the NDK to path and have to add the following lines to my `.bashrc`:

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/_path_to/android-ndk-linux/
export ANDROID_SDK=/_path_to/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK
```

In my terminal I wrote....

```
~/.bashrc
```

But it says bash:

```
/home/user/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

How can I change permission to write to `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just type the name of the file to edit it.

You need some editor like Nano or Vim.

```
vim ~/.bashrc
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not permissions but rather what you are doing when you type this:

```
~/.bashrc
```

By typing simply doing  `~/.bashrc`, the `bash` interpreter believes you want to *execute* `~/.bashrc` as if it was a binary or executable file. Which won’t work. The `Permission denied` error most likely comes from there being no executable rights on the file. But even if that was set the attempt would still fail with a different error message.

If you need to edit `~/.bashrc` you need to open it up with an editor such as `nano` like this:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Make your edits. Save it. And all should be good.  And you might have to reload the `~/.bashrc` to ensure your changes are loaded. You can do this by exiting and then re-opening a terminal session. Or running `source` on the file like so:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```